# Is there a way to do this in SAS/SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I have three 3 database tables. One of them is the master table and the rest are used for references.
[image: A snapshot of the master table is below]

The weather and season are tables themselves but the only information they hold is an integer value ranging from 1 to 4. I need to create an SQL/SAS query that basically evaluates through the permutations of weather and season i.e `weather=1` and `season=1,2,3,4`, `weather=2` and `season=1,2,3,4`.

I attempted to do this with inline queries but I am not sure if I am correct. Here's what I have -

```
proc sql;
    select
        avg(casual_renter),
        weather,
        season
    from
        db1
    where
        weather in
        (
            select weather
            from db2
        )
    group by weather;
quit;
```

The end result of the data obtained from this query is to basically compare the effect of weather and season on the rental patterns.

Comment: Why does it need to use PROC SQL?  Why not just use PROC MEANS?

Comment: Don't post sample data as photographs. Also the variable CASUAL_RENTER in your program does not appear in your picture of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you basically want your master table with all possible permutations/combinations of the 2 other reference tables.

The trick with this is not to have a join but rather just select from the tables.

Here is an example for you:

[DB Fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b0e6f049b9c81368995602dc2c7586b3)

Comment: Basically, the master table contains all the weather and season data. I need to calculate the average by modifying the values of weather and season. Ideally it should be like this `where weather = 1 and season=1` , `where weather=1 and season=2` along those lines. Was that a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

A cross join will create a result set that is permutations.

You can either

- have external tables enumerating the allowed values of the the variables
- create the list of 'allowed' values from the data being processed.  Note:  This may miss permutations that *could* occur but don't because the data itself may be missing some value across all the rows.

The cross join concept often comes into play when dealing with procedures that feature a `CLASSDATA` option.

Once you have the permutations you can left join to it as you compute group-wise aggregates.

Example:

```
proc sql;
  create table seasons (season num);
  create table weathers (weather num);

  insert into seasons
    values(1)
    values(2)
    values(3)
    values(4) 
  ;

  insert into weathers select season as weather from seasons;

  create table want as
  select 
    perm.weather
  , perm.season
  , mean(casual_renter) as cas_rent_mean
  from 
    (select weather, season from weathers cross join seasons) as perm
  left join 
    have
  on
    perm.weather = have.weather and
    perm.season  = have.season
  group by
    perm.weather, perm.season
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use SQL?  You can use PROC MEANS to calculate the mean of CASUAL_RENTER.  If you want to fill out the results so that all possible season*weather combinations are included use the CLASSDATA option.

```
proc means data=have nway classdata=classdata;
  class season weather;
  var casual_renter;
run;
```

You can make the CLASSDATA dataset easily in this case with a simple data step.

```
data classdata;
  do season=1 to 4;
    do weather=1 to 4;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

If the problem is more complex and you need to build it from your source datasets then a simple SQL query will do that. So if you have SEASON and WEATHER datasets that have variables SEASON and WEATHER, respectively then this code will do.

```
proc sql;
  create classdata as select distinct season,weather from season,weather ;
quit;
```